# Does PHP wait for mysql query result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code snippet looks like this. First two lines will insert some data to a table and the file included on the third line will work on that data. The insert may take few seconds. Will PHP wait for result from MySQL query before going to the third line code which will include other PHP file ? Do I need to add `sleep()` in between those two database operations ?

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO STAGINGINDEX(SYMBOL,TURNOVER,CURRENT) VALUES (TRIM('{$full_index[$i]}'),TRIM({$full_index[$i+1]}),TRIM({$full_index[$i+2]}))";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 


    include 'index_insert.php'; // this php code works on the data that is inserted by above query
```

Comment: in this case yes the PHP code will wait making it a blocking query.. mysqli_query has a resultmode param with MYSQLI_ASYNC option to make it a non-blocking query meaning the PHP execution continues without waiting on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes I didn't know about that, just looking up now.  There are a few async things in PHP but in general, everything should be assumed to be synchronous in PHP.  It looks like MYSQLI_ASYNC isn't truely asynchronous because it can still only handle one query at a time.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. So it is safe to use this code. There is no way the included file will get executed before the insert completes on the database.

Comment: never used MYSQLI_ASYNC @Devon and i never will use MYSQLI_ASYNC looks to tricky to get the PHP code working correctly.. imagine if you create a table in MYSQLI_ASYNC mode and directly INSERT i hope MySQL already has created the table before the INSERT happen.. Likely not because a CREATE TABLE statement wil trigger disk I/O which is slow.

Comment: I agree, although MySQL is often what slows down your code, it's usually not something you want to be performed asynchronously, especially with inserts or updates.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I wanted to set your answer as correct answer but you have answered as a comment. Can you copy paste it to answers section so I can mark it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the codes are executed line by line so it will first read your $sql before will include your file.

Comment: I know they will be executed line by line but will PHP wait for query to finish before including the file.

Comment: yes it will get all data first or whatever is before that include file